# WP8 - Binding a value with a float to String conversion

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a couple of gauges in my app, and I can't figure out how to add a converter to the text binding. I read a couple of guides on msdn but I didn't manage to figure that out (I've been coding for WP8 for just a couple of weeks).

This is is a piece of the gauge:

```
<gauges:MarkerGaugeIndicator Value="0" 
                                             gauges:LinearGaugeRange.IndicatorOffset="35"
                                             x:Name="GaugeBarValore"
                                             IsAnimated="True">
                                    <gauges:MarkerGaugeIndicator.MarkerTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Width="73" Height="35" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Margin="10,-2,0,0">
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="GaugeBarPercent" Text="{Binding}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="20"
                                           FontWeight="Thin" Margin="6,4,32,4" Width="35"/>
                                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" TranslateX="49" TranslateY="12" />
                                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </gauges:MarkerGaugeIndicator.MarkerTemplate>
                                </gauges:MarkerGaugeIndicator>
```

The binding itself works, but I can see a lot of decimal numbers while the value moves from a round value to another.
I want to add a converter like this method:

```
private String double2String(double valore)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(Math.Round(valore)) + "%";
    }
```

I just don't know where to put this method and how to add this as a converter inside the binding.

Thank you for your help! :)
Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to hold your Converter method that implements IValueConverter interface, Example class is bellow. You have to implement method Convert and ConvertBack.

```
public class DoubleToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Math.Round((double)value).ToString() + "%";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.Parse(value as string);
    }
}
```

then add the namespace to your XAML page.

```
xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:Your_project_name"
```

Next add your converter as a Resource type i to your XAML page..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <convert:DoubleToString x:Key="DoubleConvert" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The x:Key value is the name we are going to call in our binding statement.

Then perform the data binding. I have a simple slider and a textblock with sliders value bound to the textblocks Text property

```
<StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="slider" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConvert}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! It gives me a "xaml not valid" message though, and it underlines in blue those xaml lines.
I don't get how is it possible that the app compiles and run fine with the converter, even if it's saying the xaml is not valid.

This is the binding: Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DoubleConvert}}"

Am I missing something to put there?

Comment: Is it there even after you have build the solution. Its there coz initially you haven't build the project and the DoubleToString class name is not in effect so to speak. Its not recognized. It should be done after you have build the solution.

Comment: Nope, I run the app both in the emulator and on the phone, it's still there. It underlines everything inside the <DataTemplate></DataTemplate> area. And the two <DataTemplate></DataTemplate> are underlined as well... :/

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem you are having. But works fine in my project. are you using telerik controls for the gauges? And you are setting the value for the binding from the code ryt?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Telerik Controls.
This is the whole xaml code of that gauge: http://pastebin.com/y4RsX54K
I'm setting the values of the gauge bar and the indicator that the binding is pointing to in the code, yes.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Define this converter as a resource in your parent view

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <local:double2String x:Key="convertDouble" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And add it to the binding

```
<TextBlock x:Name="GaugeBarPercent" Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource convertDouble}}"
```

Don't forget to import the namespace where the converter is defined to your view

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOUR_NAMESPACE"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to use StringFormat. Like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, StringFormat='{0:F2}%' }"/>
```